# How to use http.HandleFunc with slugs

Tags: http, go, handle, slug

I am working on a Go project. When I try to use slugs with http.HandleFunc I get a "404 page not found error". When I take the slug out my routing works again.

In main I have:

```
  http.HandleFunc("/products/feedback/{slug}", AddFeedbackHandler)
```

Which calls:

```
var AddFeedbackHandler = http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
  w.Write([]byte("ChecksOut"))
})
```

When I replace the path with:

```
  http.HandleFunc("/products/feedback", AddFeedbackHandler)
```

It works again. What might be causing this?

Comment: AWAIK, current Golang's http library does not support captureing `{slug}` in the path,  maybe you should use something like https://github.com/gorilla/mux

Comment: Note that the documentation for HandleFunc doesn't claim to support slugs. The Go documentation is pretty good, you can generally assume that functionality not document doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
const feedbackPath = "/products/feedback/"  // note trailing slash.

func AddFeedbackHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  var slug string
  if strings.HasPrefix(r.URL.Path, feedbackPath) {
      slug = r.URL.Path[len(feedbackPath):]
  }
  fmt.Println("the slug is: ", slug)
  w.Write([]byte("ChecksOut"))
}
```

Add the handler with this code:

```
http.HandleFunc(feedbackPath, AddFeedbackHandler)
```

The trailing slash on the path is required for a subtree match. You can read the details on the use of the trailing slash in the [ServeMux documentation](https://godoc.org/net/http#ServeMux).

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/fVP2G3CeMW)

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, but what is the function of colon (:) sign at the slug variable assignment?

Comment: @amerw `r.URL.Path[len(feedbackPath):]` is a [slice expression](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) that evaluates to the part of the path following `/products/feedback/`.